# Did the Oracle's pats prevent Smith from copying himself over Neo?

Tags: the-matrix

Before the Burly Brawl, the Oracle put on a black glove and patted Neo reassuringly.

That was also where Smith later penetrated into Neo's body and tried to copy over him.

However, Neo was able to prevent it. Was it because of the Oracle's help?

[image]

Comment: Smith does assimilate the Oracle, so I'm guessing **no**. But I'm no expert.

Comment: I just want to say that no matter how many times i see these movies i always found something new.

Comment: @KinzieB you found something before me. :D

Comment: @CássioRenan the Oracle let Smith assimilate... to Smith's discomfort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [film's script](http://www.whoaisnotme.net/scripts/TMRL_2001_UD.pdf) indicates that it was Neo's *willpower* (presumably coupled with his being "the one") that enabled him to resist Smith's takeover attempt.

The pat on his chest isn't even mentioned in the screenplay, nor in the earlier version of the script, suggesting that it was just a cinematic touch added by the Directors to show that the Oracle genuinely cares for Neo.

> Neo begins to panic, fear clouds his eyes.
>
> **AGENT SMITH:**  *Yes, that's it. It will be over soon.*
>
> **Focusing the entirety of his will, Neo slowly takes hold of Smith's arm.**
>
> The Smiths all look at each other, simultaneously  experiencing the
>   same disbelief.
>
> The blackness spreading like liquid obsidian suddenly stops as **Neo
>   summons a final surge** and shaking from the effort, rips the fingers
>   from his chest— Severing the connection, the darkness instantly
>   evaporating.

Comment: So he didn't ["Safely Remove Device"](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-au/windows7/safely-remove-devices-from-your-computer)?

Comment: @Mooz - Agent Smith is clearly hot-swappable.

Comment: "a cinematic touch added by the Directors to show the Oracle's" - Is this a cliffhanger for a sequel we should be expecting?

Comment: @Ellesedil - Most everything they've [made](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1617661/) since has [been](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1371111/) total [dreck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speed_Racer_(film)). A sequel trilogy to the Matrix is now only a matter of time.